# BOOST::PYTHON Setting the namespace of a boost::python::object with cppyy

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python, cppyy

We are trying to set the namespace of a `boost::python::object`, with the following code

In PyROOTGlobals.h we declare:

```
#ifndef PyROOTGlobals_h
#define PyROOTGlobals_h

#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace Kolophon{

 class PyROOTGlobals {

  public:

  ~PyROOTGlobals();
  const boost::python::object &wuto() const { return WutoAtlas; }

  private:
  PyROOTGlobals();

  boost::python::object WutoAtlas;
 };
}
#endif
```

And in PyROOTGlobals.cc we declare:

```
PyROOTGlobals::PyROOTGlobals()
{
  Py_Initialize();
  pyCintex = boost::python::import("cppyy");
  pyROOT = boost::python::import("ROOT");

  WutoAtlas = pyCintex.attr("Namespace")("WutoAtlas");

  mainDict = boost::python::import("__main__").attr("__dict__");

  boost::python::object builtins =
  mainDict["__builtins__"].attr("__dict__");

  compileFn = builtins["compile"];
  evalFn = builtins["eval"];

  //errorhandling
  StringIO = boost::python::import("io");
  sysModule = boost::python::import("sys");
  commonModule = boost::python::import("common");
}
```

But when using `WutoAtlas = pyCintex.attr("Namespace")("WutoAtlas")` we get a `boost::python::error_already_set` error. We also tried `setattr(WutoAtlas,"Namespace","WutoAtlas")` but same result.

Does anybody know how to set the namespace attribute with `cppyy`?

Comment: Print the actual Python error using `PyErr_Print()` to get a better idea. Most likely `Namespace` does not exist.

Comment: Can confirm `Namespace` was not existing